# UWP - Access to Isolated Storage

Tags: uwp, windows-mobile

I am saving pictures into isolated storage on my phone and I need to check those pictures. I have already tried WP Power tools and it worked for first time, then the tool shows nothing.

I tried ISETool too, but I get Error: "Unit cannot find specified trace or area on disc."(I dont know right translation into english)

My cmd: 
ISETool ts deviceindex:0 c8f84505-4b6f-4241-92c2-c35b011ae79a C:\Users\j.cihlar\Documents

IsoStoreSpy is not for Win 10 so I have no idea what to use...

EDIT:
[image: This is the error when I try to use WP power tools]

Comment: Not totally clear...  Is this your app or something else?  Is it a HTML/JS app?

Comment: IsoStoreSpy works fine for W10 apps - try to select device, then your app and it should work.

Comment: Henk Holterman - I created app for UWP in C#. I am using it on my phone

Comment: Every time I run IsoStoreSpy I get "program stopped working" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Device portal`:

1. On your phone go to `Settings > Update & security > For developers` and enable `Device discovery` and `Device portal`.
2. On your PC go to address show below the `Device portal` section.
3. Click the `Pair` button in `Device discovery` section and write the shown code to the textbox in your browser and submit it.
4. In browser in section `App File Explorer` is shown folder `LocalAppData` folder where are your app's data.

For security reasons I recommend to turn off the `Device portal` and `Device discovery` when it's not needed!